# After migration from v6.4 to v6.5.3 Links from the menu bar result in a 500 HTTP error

Tags: kiwi-tcms

After migrating a Kiwi TCMS instance running on v6.4 forward to v6.5.3 the menu bar links (for creating test cases, searching for test cases, plans, runs, ...) render a 500 HTTP error.

```
web_1_39d351b5ac37 | 10.24.100.169 - - [07/Mar/2019:11:04:26 +0000] "GET /plans/search/ HTTP/1.1" 500 10346 "https://xxxxxxxxxx:8443/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36"
```

What Did I do for migration:

1. Created a backup of database and attachments from v6.4 instance
2. Created a fresh v6.4 instance
3. Imported backup into v6.4 instance
4. Upgraded Docker image to v6.5.3 and recreated Docker containers
5. Run migration

Earlier I did a migration from V5.1 up to v6.5.3 (with intermediate steps according to the migration steps) which resulted in the same issue.

Anyone else experiencing this?

This is the first line of error reported to the browser with Debug = true settings:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /plans/search/
testplans/search.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://xxxxxx:8443/plans/search/
Django Version: 2.1.7
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
testplans/search.html
Exception Location: /venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in get_template, line 19
Python Executable:  /venv/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.6.3
Python Path:    
['/Kiwi',
 '/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/venv/lib64/python36.zip',
 '/venv/lib64/python3.6',
 '/venv/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6',
 '/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tcms/core/lib']
```

The following is reported to the console:

```
web_1_c758cf247b33 | xx.xx.xx.xx - - [21/Mar/2019:12:29:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1811 "https://tcms.xx:8443/runs/search/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36"
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:29:56.184167 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64058] Internal Server Error: /plans/new/
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:29:56.184214 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64058] Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:29:56.184219 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64058]   File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:29:56.184224 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64058]     response = get_response(request)
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:29:56.184228 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64058]   File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:29:56.184233 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64058]     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:29:56.184237 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64058]   File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:29:56.184241 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64058]     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:29:56.184245 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64058]   File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:29:56.184252 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64058]     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:29:56.184256 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64058]   File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 45, in _wrapper
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:29:56.184260 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64058]     return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:29:56.184265 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64058]   File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:29:56.184269 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64058]     return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:29:56.184273 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64058]   File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:29:56.184277 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64058]     return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:29:56.184281 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64058]   File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tcms/testplans/views.py", line 63, in get
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:29:56.184285 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64058]     return render(request, self.template_name, context_data)
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:29:56.184289 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64058]   File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:29:56.184294 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64058]     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:29:56.184298 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64058]   File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:29:56.184302 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64058]     template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:29:56.184306 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64058]   File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 19, in get_template
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:29:56.184310 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64058]     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:29:56.184316 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64058] django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: testplans/mutable.html
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:29:56.184324 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64058]
web_1_c758cf247b33 | xx.xx.xx.xx - - [21/Mar/2019:12:29:56 +0000] "GET /plans/new/ HTTP/1.1" 500 109021 "https://tcms.xx:8443/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36"
web_1_c758cf247b33 | xx.xx.xx.xx - - [21/Mar/2019:12:30:17 +0000] "-" 408 - "-" "-"
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:30:23.334989 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64099] Internal Server Error: /plans/search/
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:30:23.335022 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64099] Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:30:23.335027 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64099]   File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:30:23.335032 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64099]     response = get_response(request)
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:30:23.335036 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64099]   File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:30:23.335041 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64099]     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:30:23.335045 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64099]   File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:30:23.335050 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64099]     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:30:23.335054 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64099]   File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py", line 40, in inner
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:30:23.335062 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64099]     return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:30:23.335066 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64099]   File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tcms/testplans/views.py", line 169, in search
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:30:23.335071 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64099]     return render(request, 'testplans/search.html', context_data)
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:30:23.335075 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64099]   File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:30:23.335079 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64099]     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:30:23.335083 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64099]   File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:30:23.335088 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64099]     template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:30:23.335093 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64099]   File "/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 19, in get_template
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:30:23.335097 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64099]     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:30:23.335103 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64099] django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: testplans/search.html
web_1_c758cf247b33 | [Thu Mar 21 12:30:23.335111 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 11] [remote xx.xx.xx.xx:64099]
web_1_c758cf247b33 | xx.xx.xx.xx - - [21/Mar/2019:12:30:23 +0000] "GET /plans/search/ HTTP/1.1" 500 95055 "https://tcms.xx:8443/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Provide some logs b/c there's nothing I can help you with without them. We need to see that the actual traceback is.

Comment: Can you give me a hint how/where to get more/detailled log. The info above is from the console log (the docker container log) fir the kiwi_web Docker container. I would assume that the Docker container would already log all available log output from the application. Do I need to set some logging level ?

Comment: docker compose up (without -D) will print the access log and error log on the terminal. In production mode Django tracebacks are sent directly to apache's error log. You should be able to see that on ther terminal without changing the default seetings.

Comment: I had to set the `Debug = true` setting in order to get some more detailled error information. Running docker-compose up or docker-compose up -d does not really change anything else but sending the container to the background. The `docker container logs` command really shows the same log output as if it was started in foreground (just in case someone else hits that). 

I have added the error reported to browser / console to the text above.

Comment: Try the 6.6 version which we have released this week. The problem is that some of the template files are not found but I have no idea why. Check on the file system inside the container if these files are present and then post the value of TEMPLATES setting. The migration part here has nothing to do with this problem. Either you have overriden some settings or you are using a bogus docker image where testplans/search.html is missing

Comment: I'm trying to build v6.6 with `make docker-image`. This results in

make docker-image
....
....

`usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
Makefile:71: recipe for target 'docker-image' failed
make: *** [docker-image] Error 1`

Comment: Is this with Python 3.6? You need to be able to build wheel and tar.gz packages.

Comment: I certainly would appreciate if a docker image could be published for a released Kiwi Tcms version. Thanks

Comment: Public docker images are not versioned and will never be. We only provide versioned images for intermediate releases which will break the upgrade process otherwise.  This is what you get for free. CentOS for example provides their Docker images in the same manner. We do have git tags so the rest is up to you if you have the time and experience to deal with it.